# Is this simple reflective separative theory inconsistent?

Tags: set-theory, reflection

Working in *mono-sorted* first order logic with membership:

- *Define:* $set(x) \equiv_{df} \exists y \,  (x \in y)$
- *Define:* $a \approx b \equiv_{df} \forall x \, (a \in x \leftrightarrow b \in x)$
- Axiomatize:

1. **Extensionality:** $( set(a) \to[ (a \subseteq b \land b \subseteq a) \leftrightarrow a \approx b])$
2. **Separation:** $(set(a) \to \exists \ set \ x : \forall y \, (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \land \phi ))$
3. **Reflection:** $ (\phi \to \exists \ set \ x : \text { trs}(x) \land \phi^x)$

where formula $\phi$ doesn't use $``x"$ in both schemata; $\phi^x$ is the formula obtained from $\phi$ by merely bounding all of its quantifiers by $``\subseteq x"$; and $\text { trs}(x) \iff \forall y \in x (y \subseteq x)$

This theory seems to prove all axioms of $\sf ZF-Reg.$ over the set world of it, and perhaps can even go beyond that? But, my guess is that it is inconsistent!

> Is there a clear inconsistency with this theory?

Comment: Doesn't ZFC imply this theory?

Comment: @JunderscoreH No. If we bounded the quantifiers by $\in x$ instead of $\subseteq x$, then all these statements would be theorems of ZF. This theory proves $\exists M . (\neg set(M))$, which contradicts ZF.

Comment: You can also use \iff for $\iff$ and \implies for $\implies$.

Comment: @MarkSaving . How do you derive $\exists M\,(\neg set(M))$ ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Suppose not; then take some $x$ such that $\forall M \subseteq x (M \in x)$. But this cannot be true by Russell’s paradox; in particular, consider $\{v \in x \mid v \notin v\}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, For a proof by negation, let $\phi$ be the formula $\neg \exists M (\forall y \, (y \in M \iff set(y) \land y \not \in y))$, now if no proper class exist then this formula is true, then by reflection we have: $\exists \ set \ x: \neg \exists M \subseteq x (\forall y \subseteq x \, (y \in M \iff y \in x \land y \not \in y))$ which is false because of Separation, so  $\neg \phi$ must be true, which proves existence of the Russell's class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this theory is inconsistent.

We note that by 1 and 2 that if set(x) and y⊆x, then set(y).

(a) There is a v such that ∀x(set(x)-->x∈v).

Proof:Suppose not. Then ∀v∃s∃t(s∈t∧s∉v). By 3 there is transitive x such that

```
  set(x) and ∀v(v⊆x-->∃s∃t(s⊆x∧t⊆x∧s∈t∧s∉v). In particular 

  (x⊆x-->∃s∃t(s⊆x∧t⊆x∧s∈t∧s∉x).  But this is impossible.
```

Suppose that ∀x(set(x)-->x∈V). Then ∃w∀t(t∈V-->t∈w). By 3 there is transitive x

such that set(x) and ∃w(w⊆x∧∀t(t⊆x∧t∈V-->t∈w)). Since t⊆x implies set(t),

t⊆x implies t∈x. By 2, there is a c such that t∈c<-->(t∈x∧t∉t). Since set(c),

c∈c<-->c∉c.